# A visually guided proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-writing, roots

A complex root of a polynomial $P(z)$ is a pair of real numbers $u,v$ that simultaneously make the real part and the imaginary part of $P(z)$ zero.

The zeros of the real part and the imaginary part are given by two curves in the complex plane

$$\operatorname{Re}(P(u +iv)) = 0$$

$$\operatorname{Im}(P(u+iv)) = 0$$

The zeros of the polynomial are the intersection points of these two curves.

For the sake of specifity here are the two curves for [$P(z) = z^5 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q5g2vqtcbd):

$u^5-6u^3v^2-4v^2u^3+5uv^4+ u^3-v^2u-2uv^2+u^2-v^2+u+1 = 0 $

$v^5+5vu^4-10u^2v^3+3u^2v-v^3+2uv+v=0$

The fundamental theorem of algebra says that such curves always do intersect. A proof of the fundamental theorem might go like this: The curves $\operatorname{Re}(P(z)) = 0$ (red) and $\operatorname{Im}(P(z)) = 0$ (blue) – which are [tightly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2961842/1792) – are such-and-such, so they must intersect at least once and at most $n$ times (for $n$ the degree of the polynomial).

What can be seen is, that the curves always come in $n$ branches which extend to infinity and for some reason must intersect.

[image] [$x^2 + x + 1$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/idpiuhdazo)

[image] [$x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wrn3daymdc)

[image] [$x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/afjqfiktvq)

[image] [$x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q5g2vqtcbd)

How could such a proof be spelled out?

Comment: Why must have $\operatorname{Re}(P(u +iv))$ zeroes at all?

Comment: Because $P(z) = 0$ iff $\operatorname{Re}(P(z)) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(P(z)) = 0$?

Comment: Clear as mud; but was ensures you that the real part has zeroes at all?

Comment: This has to be proved, it's part of the proof. (We know it because FTA is true.)

Comment: See also [The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: A Visual Approach](https://acdc.amherst.edu/view/octagon:144/CONTENT) by Velleman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That idea is basically the approach to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra taken by Gauss, in his PhD thesis [*Demonstratio nova theorematis omnem functionem algebraicam rationalem integram unius variabilis in factores reales primi vel secundi gradus resolvi posse*](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Demonstratio_nova_theorematis_omnem_functionem_algebraicam_rationalem_integram_unius_variabilis_in_factores_reales_primi_vel_secundi_gradus_resolvi_posse). It's a nice geometrical approach to the theorem, but hard to complete rigorously. I suggest that you read [C. F. Gauss’s  proofs of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/C.-F.-GAUSS%E2%80%99S-PROOFS-OF-THE-FUNDAMENTAL-THEOREM-OF-CAIN/95ff48fce4d89353697e76c32f6bc1258b5f9279), by Harel Cain.

Comment: What a nice paper! Thank you very much.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.06585