# A visible sketch of a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

There is a visible sketch of a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra. For the polynomial $f(z)=a_0+a_1z\cdots + a_nz^n$ over $\mathbb C$, with $a_0\neq 0$, define a function $g_r:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb C$ by $g_r(\phi)=f(re^{i\phi})$. Given an open disk $\mathcal O_r\subset\mathbb C$ such that $0\notin\mathcal O_r\ni a_0$. If $r>0$ is small enough the image 
$\operatorname{Im} g_r\subset\mathcal O_r$. On the other hand, if $r$ is big enough the term $a_nz^n$ totally dominates and since the transformation of $\operatorname{Im} g_r$ as $r$ groves is continuous there must be an $r$ such that $0\in\operatorname{Im} g_r$.

> Is it possible to make this proof rigorous with elementary methods and
>   without an unreasonable effort?

Comment: Yes, it is! Check out the answers at [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra). Also, [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961884/a-visually-guided-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra) is related.

Comment: Do you consider a notion of "fundamental group" elementary? If yes, then you may look here: http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/eng-book-nopfs.pdf. At pages 192-193 of the book (207-208 of pdf-file) there is a simple topological proof with the similar idea.

Comment: @Zeekless: this seems to be a nice text book.

Comment: @Lehs, I like it a lot. Sorry, I have given a link to the version with no proofs. Here is the full one (proofs go after chapters): http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/e-unstable.pdf.